# ARC semantic Issue, Semantic issue error.

Tags: ios, iphone, location, augmented-reality, semantics

I've downloaded this [Raywenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42266/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-location-based) and I am having a problem with this part of code.

I am still new in iOS development and I cant understand what does it means. I have searched over the internet but none of those is the answer.

Please help me on this.

```
int index = [_locations indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[obj location] isEqual:location];
}];
```

There are 3 errors are as following:

> Multiple methods named 'location' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes
>
> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(__strong id, NSUInteger, BOOL *)' to parameter of type 'BOOL (^)(__strong id, NSUInteger, BOOL *)'
>
> Bad receiver type 'CGFloat' (aka 'float')

Here is the complete code where you can find this line:

```
- (void)didTouchMarkerView:(MarkerView *)markerView 
{
    ARGeoCoordinate *tappedCoordinate = [markerView coordinate];
    CLLocation *location = [tappedCoordinate geoLocation];

    int index = [_locations indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[obj location] isEqual:location];
    }]; 

    if(index != NSNotFound) 
    {
        Place *tappedPlace = [_locations objectAtIndex:index];
        [[PlacesLoader sharedInstance] loadDetailInformation:tappedPlace successHanlder:^(NSDictionary *response) {
            NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
            NSDictionary *resultDict = [response objectForKey:@"result"];
            [tappedPlace setPhoneNumber:[resultDict objectForKey:kPhoneKey]];
            [tappedPlace setWebsite:[resultDict objectForKey:kWebsiteKey]];
            [self showInfoViewForPlace:tappedPlace];
     } errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);}];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the return statement as below,

```
return [[(Place *)obj location] isEqual:location];
```

It'll remove the errors.

Comment: Had the same problem. This answer should be marked as the accepted answer for this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

As written you are passing in a block that returns `void`, but the method signature requires you to pass in a block that returns `BOOL`.

Just make this little addition to the block your passing in as an argument:

```
int index = [_locations indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
```

In the future, just hit ENTER or TAB when code completion suggests the block signature, and you won't have to worry about memorizing the syntax...

As for the multiple methods named `location` found, you have:

1. A property named `locations` which you are accessing via the synthesized getter as `_locations`
2. an instance of `CLLocation` named `location` which is scoped to the method
3. You are also making a strong promise to the program that every object stored in your `_locations` property absolutely has either a property or a method of it's own called `location`, which may or may not be equal to the method scoped `location` from #2

Might I suggest you try a tactic favored by the "Clean Code" people and indulge in longer and more descriptive method and variable names. Simply doing that will likely highlight your `location` mismatches, and let you see what's going on.

It's hard to speculate on the CGFloat bad receiver type from the amount of code posted, but I'll wager that you have some NSNumber / CGFloat mismatch happening. You may use `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:someFloat]` to create a NSNumber, and you may call `[someNumber floatValue]` to extract a float from an NSNumber.